# Maven command runs fine on local machine, but not in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, appium

So I have a maven project that has a profile

**When I run the following in the terminal for my project, the tests will run just fine**

mvn clean install -Pserial-integration-test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @'QR_Scan'" -Dtest.environment=PrePRod

**When I run the following in a Jenkins project it will not run the tests that I need it too**

clean install -Pserial-integration-test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @'QR_Scan'" -Dtest.environment=PrePRod

**Jenkins settings**

I have setup a Jenkins Maven project and told Jenkins where my Pom is, and I send the command below for the goal and options "clean install -Pserial-integration-test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @'QR_Scan'" -Dtest.environment=PrePRod"

**Maven Settings**

serial-integration-test

```
        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <junitPlatformArtifactName>com.github.junit-team.junit5:junit-platform-engine</junitPlatformArtifactName>
                        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <test.environment></test.environment>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generateRunners</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <name>com.gm.onstar.rita.cucumber.CucumberReporter</name>
                                    </plugin>
                                </plugins>
                                <glue>
                                    <package>com.gm.onstar.rita.stepdefinitions</package>
                                </glue>
                                <featuresDirectory>src/main/resources/features</featuresDirectory>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>${cucumber.tag1}</tag>
                                    <tag>${cucumber.tag2}</tag>
                                    <tag>${cucumber.tag3}</tag>
                                    <tag>${cucumber.tag4}</tag>
                                    <tag>${cucumber.tag5}</tag>
                                    <tag>~@Ignore</tag>
                                </tags>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried putting in like this in Jenkins -Dcucumber.options="--tags @QR_Scan" and like this -Dcucumber.options='--tags @QR_Scan'
2. I have tried putting the profile -Pserial-integration-test with a space and without a space -P serial-integration-test
3. I have tried to see if I a missing some sort of plugin
4. I have tried to see if Mvn clean install or Mvn clear verify would run it on Jenkins

**What it might be.**

1. Jenkins does not like that my cucumber runner is in the main and not in java test folder?
2. Am I missing a plugin for Jenkins?
3. Am I typing the command in wrong in jenkins, and maybe missing some parentheses or something?

**Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!**

Comment: Compare the logs from running locally and running on Jenkins and see where they differ.

Comment: I found out the issue. So I was running from local repo, and I did not know that you still had to commit your code in order for Jenkins to pick it up. Oops o0. Thanks for your help!